# How to prevent a script from running when email does not pass filter_var

Tags: php, filter-var

I'm trying to make the emails pass validation by using filter_var. However, I am not sure how to prevent the script from processing the form data to my database if the email is not valid.

I have

```
    $email = $_POST['email'];
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    echo("$email is a valid email address");
} else {
    echo("$email is not a valid email address");
    exit();
  }
```

the email obviously comes from what was entered in by the user and is in the $_POST variable. The script DOES show the email as valid or invalid, however it STILL processes the script and places the form data into my database. I thought that putting "exit()" would be the solution to this, or the proper way to handle when it's not valid. It simply opens a new page where the echo print shows.

What am I missing or doing wrong? Ideally I would like the form field to highlight and give the user some indication that they've entered in an incorrectly formatted email address (although I know that is a different topic and somewhat a bells and whistles type of thing), but I certainly do not want to allow the script to process the data into my database.

Comment: You're filtering twice? Get rid of the 2nd line of your script

Comment: Your condition is `if(false === false)`

Comment: The double negative was confusing, but I think I understand it now. It's in this sample code at W3Schools http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp

Comment: I do not understand. I got that script from W3Schools (which I understand has a bad rep), and I did not understand why it would be !filter_var. but I have taken that out (the second line) and it still echos "not a valid email address" yet it still places the data into the database. How can I prevent it from doing so if it is NOT a valid (properly formed) email address?

I have also updated the code in the question.

Comment: You aren't showing us your database code.

Comment: Actually I think the second line SHOULD be there, as it is sanitizing, not validating..so not filtering twice. And what database code do I need to show? I just want the script to not execute if the email is not passing validation

Comment: The code in this sandbox works the way you expect it to. Where is your DB code in relationship to the code above? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/58bd92719f992323b8e76796217290991eb71de4

Comment: It is the first code that appears in the document. Is the order important? Please remember I am new to PHP and I am trying the best that I can, I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: Yes the code works as far as validating. But my question is how to STOP the script from placing the invalid data into the database?

As it goes now, it will echo "invalid" BUT it still puts it inside of the database. I would thnk that the exit() would prevent that.

Comment: I actually fixed it. It was in fact the placement of where I put my code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in where the validation code was placed. Instead of placing it RIGHT AFTER the posted variables and before the SQL insertion code, I put it at the very end of the script. So the posted data went into the database before they can be validated.

So now, I have (which works)
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];

```
  $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    echo("$email is not a valid email address");
    exit();
  } else {
        $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4>Thanks ' . $name . ', we will send you news when appropriate. Take care!</font></h4>';
  $name = "";
  $email = "";
  }
  // THE SQL SELECT STATEMENT TO ENSURE NO DUPLICATE EMAIL AND THEN THE INSERT STATEMENT TO PUT THE DATA IN THE DATABASE COMES AFTER THE CODE ABOVE
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont know how to edit the code so that it all fits into the answer. It should have the 
    $name=$_POST['name']; $email=$_POST['email']; 
at the top of that code.